# Баг с авторизацией на SO через VK, вхожу в чужой аккаунт

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, вконтакте

В общем история такая, зашел сегодня на SO и почему-то оказался не авторизован в своем аккаунте, возможно из-за того, что вчера vpn использовал. Но суть не в этом, я создавал профиль через фейсбук, но всегда был залогинен и забыл через какую соц сеть заходил, нажал авторизацию через ВК и тут самое интересное - я захожу в чужой аккаунт - вот этот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/285479/anastasia
Пробовал несколько раз, выхожу - захожу, опять этот акк, хотя в ВК я залогинен под своим профилем, тем же именем, что на ФБ и тут, а эту Анастасию я впервые вижу вообще, как такое может быть?

Comment: Да, действительно, ошибка есть. Уже отписался разработчикам. Как только станет известно что–либо, сразу дам знать!

Comment: Вот это дырища!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В обработке ответа от серверов ВКонтакте произошла ошибка, в результате которой мы не могли обработать ID, который все время получал значение по умолчанию. Ошибку исправили.