# Ошибка при авторизации через ВК на ru.stackoverflow.com

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

Не могу войти через ВК на свою основную страницу. Пишет:

> There was an error fetching your account from VK. Please try logging
>   in again.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: стоит написать в службу поддержки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: А не отключение ли openid, которое недавно висело в главном?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ВКонтакте работает через OAuth, а это совершенно другой протокол. И да, поддержка OpenID будет прекращена [только в июле](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/357761).

Comment: @Litras, вам ещё везло, что вы под собой вошли. А то до вас несколько людей стабильно заходили под одной и той же чужой учётной записью: «[Почему я Анастасия?)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6902/208074)», «[Баг с авторизацией на SO через VK, вхожу в чужой аккаунт](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6901/208074)».

Comment: @Arhad, так он же не вошёл. Кстати, Николас может его помёрджить.

Comment: Помёрджить на ноль.

Answer (score 3):

Мы допустили ошибку в использовании VK API. Приносим извинения за доставленные неудобства. Ошибку исправили, все должно работать. Большое спасибо за своевременный отзыв!